# Is there a way to get the precise distance of a proximity sensor from an object?

Tags: android, android-sensors, proximity

I want to get the precise distance from the device's proximity sensor to live object.

The only thing that I get is "0.0" - for near distance, and "8.0"/"7.0"(vary from on device to other) - for far distance.

thats how I use to get the distance:

```
@Override
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    final float distanceX = event.values[0];
}
```

Is there a way to get the precise distance?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The guide to position sensors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-prox) says the following about proximity sensors:

> Most proximity sensors return the absolute distance, in cm, but some
> return only near and far values.

so precision is device-dependent.

Comment: Yep I red it, but I need the precise distance anyway. maybe in some "secret" way.

Comment: There's a 'secret' way. And it is to implement your own native wrapper for proximity sensor using NDK. But first you should be sure that sensor hardware supports anything more advanced then just far/close indication. I would find out the exact hardware specification first.

Comment: i tested sensor in`*#0*#`  and it returned me sensor value but when i wanna get that grammatically i can't